# How do I add a document that exist from another collection into another collection in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a document from wishlists collection and i wanna take that document and add it to carts collection, how do I do that properly? I tried several ways but still it's doesn't work. I'm new to this Cloud Firestore thing also this is my school project so I have to finish this before February

This is my code,
sorry if it's messed up this is my first post

```js
data() {
  return {
    // Wishlists collection
    wishlists: []
  }
}


methods: {
        // Add product to carts collection on Firestore
        addToCart(id){
            db.collection('carts')
            .add({
                id: this.wishlist.id,
                product: this.wishlist.product,
                shop: this.wishlist.shop,
                price: this.wishlist.price,
                category: this.wishlist.category,
                rating: this.wishlist.rating,
                discount: this.wishlist.discount,
                offer: this.wishlist.offer,
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.wishlists.push(cart)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                connsole.log(err)
            })
        },

},

created() {
        // Fetch wishlists collection data from Firestore
        db.collection('wishlists')
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                let wishlist = doc.data()
                wishlist.id = doc.id
                this.wishlists.push(wishlist)
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            connsole.log(err)
        })
},
```

```html
I'm trying to add it through this button

<v-btn 
color="green accent-3"
depressed
rounded
@click="[addCart.snackbar = true, addToCart(wishlist.id)]"
class="addtoCart"
>
  <v-icon
  color="white"
  >
    add_shopping_cart
  </v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what isn't working? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: sorry for the late response, it doesn't show any error

Comment: i'm trying to add a document into a new collection but document that already exist in another collection

Comment: So how do you know it isn't working? When you run your code, what do you see? Consider updating your question (rather than replying in a comment) with these additional details. At the moment there isn't enough detail in your question to be able to help you.

Comment: Try logging the value of `this.wishlist` on the `addToCart()` function, it could be the case that those values are empty and that is why you are not able to add but no error occurs.